# sub sub sub selector of a navigation menu

Tags: css

i've an issue with navmenu i can not select sub sub sub ul of a navigation menu,if what would i have done it could effect to 3. ul.This is a wordpress menu i don't have chance using class or id for the menu.Thanks for your helps in advance.

```
<nav id="navigation" >
 <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
         <ul>
             <li><a href="vimeo">vimeo</a>
                 <ul>
                     <li> <a href="#">youtube</a></li><!-- this ul is what i want to apply css -->
                 </ul>
     </li>
                 </ul>
             </li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply like this :

```
#navigation ul ul ul {
    /* your css code */
}
```

Comment: I removed the `nav`... it is valid CSS so it should work. Maybe you want to set it on LI and not UL? Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: i just want to third(youtube) link proper to be seen here is  fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bergmann/62juLxjh/